# Vue is not correctly recognized by laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have had a problem with vue in laravel for some time. Basically when I go to my app.js file if I try to go to `window.Vue = require ('vue');`
gives me this error:

```
Type 'typeof import ("myFolder)' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof Vue': prototype, extend, nextTick, set, and 10 more.ts (2740).
```

If instead I go up
`Vue.component ('example-component', require ('./ components / ExampleComponent.vue'). Default)`;
It tells me `Vue 'refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts (2686).`
The visual studio quick fix suggests that I enter this

```
 import Vue from 'vue / types / umd';
```

But doing it no longer works the connection to my js 
and the console releases this error by launching the `npm run watch`

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue / types / umd' in 'C: \ Users \ rispo \ OneDrive \ Desktop \ Final Project \ BoolBnb \ resources \ js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 1: 0-32 24: 0-3 36: 14-17
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss.
```

I have already tried to install vue from the terminal, but the problem is not solved in any way. Do you have any suggestions?